# ao compilar: "warning: operation on `eventhead' may be undefined"

Tags: c

Olá, estou tentando compilar um código com esse trecho:

```
void D_PostEvent (event_t* ev)
{
    events[eventhead] = *ev;
    eventhead = (++eventhead)&(MAXEVENTS-1);
}
```

E recebo o seguinte aviso:

`` d_main.c: In function `D_PostEvent':
d_main.c:161: warning: operation on `eventhead' may be undefined ``

Alguém sabe o que faço para não aparecer esse aviso?
Obrigado!

Comment: Declare a variável `eventhead` como global ou passe como parâmetro para a função.

Answer (score 0):

resolvi escrevendo assim:
`eventhead = (eventhead+1)&(MAXEVENTS-1);`